# Disable item in angularjs directive with expression from parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items which are a custom directive and each of those items has a remove button. Now I want to disable this remove button when there is only one item left in my list, but for some reason it doesn't work as expected.

I've made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ufgPmnZUUXVpYYlxe6RE) example where you an watch this behavior.

I guess there is something wrong with the `canRemove: '&'` part of my directive. But I don't know how to get it working.

**View:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <my-directive item="item"
                      canRemove="vm.items.length != 1"
                      remove="vm.remove(item)">
        </my-directive>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.items = [
        {
            number: 1
        } , {
            number: 2
        }
    ];

    vm.remove = function(item) {
        vm.items.splice(vm.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
});
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            item: '=',
            canRemove: '&',
            remove: '&'
        },
        controller: function() {
            var vm = this;

            vm.onRemove = function() {
                vm.remove({ item: vm.item });
            };
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '<button ng-disabled="!vm.canRemove" ng-click="vm.onRemove()">' + 
                  '    Remove {{ vm.item.number }}' +
                  '</button>'
    }
});
```

**PS:** Since I'm pretty new to angular is the way I'm handling the removing of the items a good practice? Or should I use `broadcast` and `on` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all attribute should look like `can-remove`:

```
<my-directive item="item" can-remove="vm.items.length > 1" remove="vm.remove(item)"></my-directive>
```

Then in scope configuration you need to use `=` binding instead of `&`:

```
scope: {
    item: '=',
    canRemove: '=',
    remove: '&'
},
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/DlZafON6HEdoyhzvwNIh?p=preview